# Windows phone 7 navigation synchronous

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7 C#, I need to show a page and, when the page performs NavigationService.GoBack(), execute some code:

```
Save();
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Add.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
Reload();
```

But Reload() it's executed when the page in showed! How I can make the program wait for the page closing for run Reload()??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use the OnNavigatedTo method.

```
override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        Reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But if I want to access to the back page with the navigated page?

Comment: So go from Page1 to Page2 you want to access Page1 from Page2? I do not think this is possible..